# FileNotFoundError reading a csv file with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use python2 to read a csv file, using this code:

```
test = pd.read_csv('D:/GTSRB/GT-final_test.csv', sep=';')
```

but I'm getting this error:

> FileNotFoundError  Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>       118                )
>       119 
>   --> 120 test = pd.read_csv('D:/GTSRB/GT-final_test.csv', sep=';')
>       121 
>       122 # Load test dataset
>
> FileNotFoundError: File b'D:/GTSRB/GT-final_test.csv' does not exist

Comment: There is no file at that location..check spelling and other things

Comment: Try using backward slash.

Comment: @Soumendra No, that's not going to help (quite the opposite).

Comment: Could it be that Windows by default hides the extension of well-known file types. Hence while Windows shows `GT-final_test.csv` the actual name is `GT-final_test.csv.csv`?

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear. 
The file "D:/GTSRB/GT-final_test.csv" doesn't exist, so in order to fix this problem you should check if under the specified path is present the file.

If the file is present, try to modify your code as follow:

```
test = pd.read_csv(r'D:/GTSRB/GT-final_test.csv', sep=';')
```

Comment: The file is present under the  path

Comment: @CristinaHaiducu Post some screenshot of the folder then. The error HEAVILY implies that either you mispelled the path or the file simply doesn't exist at that location.

Comment: @CristinaHaiducu, i've updated my answer, try to modify the code and let me know please

Comment: The file is present in the directory and i can open it.

Comment: Can you explain what your change is supposed to accomplish?

Comment: It is possisble that the error appear because i use pyton from Google Colab ?How to upload the folder on Google Colab?

Comment: @Giordano i tried but nothing was changed-the error remain.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that 'FileNotFoundError', so you may want to check if the file exists by:

```
import os

print(os.path.exists('D:/GTSRB/GT-final_test.csv'))
```

You can also do a `os.listdir('D:/GTSRB')` to view the files within that folder.

The documentation on [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) for python could also help.

Comment: Thank you,Chen!It`s working to upload csv file but now i have this problem: